# Swift: odd XCode behaviour with required initializer in subclass of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, compilation

Issue background: I have a class that is subclass of NSArray, not directly but it is.
Structure is more or less like this `MyClass -> Class1 -> Class2 -> NSArray`.

Everything except `MyClass` is in Objective-C, MyClass is in Swift. It worked well until I upgraded to Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.

Now, during compilation it throws an error

`'required' initializer 'init(arrayLiteral:)' must be provided by subclass of 'NSArray'`

Which is pretty odd because there are other classes, siblings to `MyClass` without compilator complaining about them.
When I add the initializer,

`required convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: AnyObject...) {
   fatalError("not implemented")
}`

XCode throws another error saying `Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet`.

Does anybody have any idea what can I do? Code has zero changes at all.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are trying to subclass NSArray? Seems like it wouldn't need it unless you're doing something extremely complex.

Comment: It was there when I joined the project and "MyClass" is used in couple places in the project. It's part of the project architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just not see the compilation errors in the other files since compilation tries to stop at the first problematic file.

If you don't specify any designated initializers in your subclass or if you override all designated initializers but no convenience initializers, the problematic initializer is inherited automatically. In that case it compiles fine:

```
class MyArray1: NSArray {
    override init() { fatalError("todo") }
    override init(objects: UnsafePointer<AnyObject?>, count cnt: Int) { fatalError("todo") }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("todo") }
}


class MyArray2: MyArray1 {
}
```

This compiles just fine on Xcode 6.1.

See [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_335) in The Swift Programming Guide.

Comment: Yes, I get that so I added missing initialiser but then it causes another error, especially weird because it's not extension but subclass.

Comment: That's why I wrote not to override any **convenience initializers**. As soon as you do that you lose inheritance. And as the error messages states, you cannot override this one initializer anyway. -- You must override either **no** initializers or **all three** I used in my example - no more, no less.